# Caused by: java.lang.ClassCastException: android.app.Application cannot be cast to com.xxx

Tags: android, listview, classcastexception

After browsing multiple questions regarding that and trying multiple things, I end up with the current error.
Basically, I am trying to dynamically fill a list view by clicking a button.

For that, I have the following .xml extract:

```
    <Button
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="@string/new_exercise_button"
        android:id="@+id/exercise_add"
        android:onClick="addItems"             />
    <ListView
        android:id="@android:id/list"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:drawSelectorOnTop="false" />
```

I implemented a class RoutineListView for handling the list:

```
public class RoutineListView extends ListActivity {
    ArrayList<String> listItems=new ArrayList<String>();
    ArrayAdapter<String> adapter;

    public void onCreate(Bundle icicle) {
        super.onCreate(icicle);
        setContentView(R.layout.fragment_main);
        adapter=new ArrayAdapter<String>(this,
                android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1,
                listItems);
        setListAdapter(adapter);
    }
    public void addLItems(View v) {
        adapter.add("hi");
    }
}
```

And when the button in my main activity is clicked, I try to invoke the method with the following code in my MainActivity:

```
public void addItems(View v){
    RoutineListView routineListView = (RoutineListView)this.getApplicationContext();
    routineListView.addLItems(v);
}
```

However, debugger throws me the following error for the `getApplicationContext()` - if I don't implement it, I get a null exception for `adapter.add()`.

> Caused by: java.lang.ClassCastException: android.app.Application cannot be cast to com.mycompany.ownfitnesstracker.RoutineListView

And last, but not least, I registered my `RoutineListView` in the manifest:

```
    <activity
        android:name=".RoutineListView"
        android:label="@string/routine_list_name" >
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.GET_CONTENT" />
            <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT" />
        </intent-filter>
    </activity>
```

Comment: Can you please show your code from the MainActivity?

Comment: and the stack trace of the error

Answer (score 1):

RoutineListView is an `Activity`, not an `Application`. `getApplicationContext()` does not return an `Activity`. You can't obtain a reference to a RoutineListView this way.

There are certain ways to communicate between activities, but rarely does that involve direct method invocations from one to another. Most of the time you use `Intent`s, or you store data outside the activities (e.g. with `SharedPreferences`).

Answer (score 0):

You can directly call `addItems` without using an object.

```
public void addItems(View v){
    addLItems(v);
}
```